# Find the opposite number in the array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to find the opposite number in the array.

Let's say we have this array: `[1,3,4,-3]`

What I want is:

```
{ '1': 1, '3': 2, '4': 1 } // as we have two 3
```

and what I tried is :

```js
  const arr = [1,3,4,-3]
  let holder = {}
  arr.map(a => {
    holder[a] = (holder[a] ||0)+1
  })
      
  console.log(holder)
```

Any idea how can I acheive this ?

Comment: hint `Math.abs()`

Comment: map() is the wrong thing to use. Just for forEach or reduce

Comment: The opposite? It looks like you want to count the occurrences of an absolute value in an array. Am I right?

Comment: @epascarello I used your hint : ```arr.map(a => {
    holder[Math.abs(a)] = (holder[Math.abs(a)] ||0)+1
  })```
but this will add +1 to positive items that happen multiple times like : [1,2, -2, 3,3,3]

Comment: So check if it negative

Comment: And again, map is when you are building a new array. use forEach

Comment: @dfvc by opposite I meant values like this : 3, -3

Comment: And you never mentioned the 3, 3, 3 requirement.... so news to us.

Comment: @epascarello true, I didn't notice

Comment: @epascarello could you please give me an example of to do this ?

Comment: what is the expected output of ```[1,1,1,-2, 3,3,-3, 4,-4,-4]``` ?

Comment: @grodzi Hi, it should be ```{ '1': 1, '-2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 2}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules can be summed up as follow:

Let `v` be the array
Let `x` a positive number in the array

1. if `x` is in `v` but not `-x`, keep `{[x]:1}`
2. if `x` is in `v` and `-x` also, keep `{[x]:2}`

Let `y` a negative number in the array

- if `y` is in `v` and `-y` also do nothing (symetry of 2.)

3. if `y` is in `v` but not `-y`, keep `{[y]:1}`

Now it is pretty straightforward:

- build a set of values of `v`
- check all the positive keys
- foreach one, check if there exists its opposite and apply 1. or 2.
- delete any opposite keys
- for the remaining keys (which are then negative and have no opposite) apply 3.

```js
const v = [1,1,1,-2, 3,3,-3, 4,-4,-4]
const output = {}
const s = new Set(v)
const positives = [...new Set(v.filter(x => x>= 0))]
positives.forEach(p => {
  if (s.has(-p)) {
    output[p] = 2
    s.delete(-p)
  } else {
    output[p] = 1
  }
  s.delete(p)
})
;[...s].forEach(negative => {
  output[negative] = 1
})

console.log('output', output)
```

Now we can be a bit more aggressive regarding the symetry:
if x === -y

- upon iterating x, setting `{keep[x]: 2}`
- then upon iterating `-y`, setting `{keep[-y]: 2}` is equivalent to setting `{keep[x]: 2}` which has already been done.
  So we may or may not set `{keep[-y]: 2}`, this is equivalent

```js
const v = [1,1,1,-2, 3,3,-3, 4,-4,-4]
const output = {}
const s = new Set(v)
;[...s].forEach(x => {
  if (s.has(-x)) {
    output[Math.abs(x)] = 2
  } else {
    output[x] = 1
  }
})
console.log('output', output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is really what you trying to achieve. If so, you can do it with a `reduce`. Please check:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 4, -3];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  [Math.abs(cur)]: (acc[Math.abs(cur)] || 0) + 1,
}), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1,3,4,-3];

const allPositive = arr.map(item => Math.abs(item));

const reducer = (acc, item, index) => {
  const count = allPositive.filter(x => x===item).length;
  acc[item] = count;
  return acc
};

const result = allPositive.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(result)
```